# Appending data into dictionary causes error in swift script

Tags: swift, linux

On trying to pretty print a valid JSON object I got stuck in an error that I am unable to circumvent. The problem started when I tried to append information into a dictionary and a extension for Dictionary was necessary for this task.

The aim of the code is to create an extension template for Albert launcher in **Linux**.

The error is:

```
./org.albert.extension.external.snippy.swift:10:21: warning: no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
    let jsonS = try String(data: jsonD, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                ^
fatal error: Error raised at top level: The operation could not be completed: file /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-4.0-package-linux-ubuntu-16_10/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 187
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f089c352bc0 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile + 221
```

And the code is:

```
#! /usr/bin/swift
import Glibc
import Foundation

let albert_op = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["ALBERT_OP"]

extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    func toPrettyJSON() throws -> String? {
        let jsonD = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self,options: [.prettyPrinted])
        let jsonS = try String(data: jsonD, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return jsonS 
    }   
}

if albert_op  == "METADATA" {
    let metadata : [String: Any] = [
        "iid": "org.albert.extension.external/v2.0",
        "name": "snippets",
        "version": "0.1",
        "author": "lf-araujo",
        "dependencies": [],
        "trigger": "snip "
    ]

    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: metadata)
    let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    print(JSONString)

} else if albert_op == "QUERY"  {
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let filelist = try filemgr.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "~/.snippy")

  func buildItem(name: String) -> [String:Any] {
    let action : [String: Any] = [
        "name": name
    ]
    return action
  }

  var items : [String: Any] = [:]
  items["items"] = filelist.map { buildItem(name: $0) }

  if let jsonStr = try? items.toPrettyJSON() {
      print(jsonStr!)
  }

}

exit(0)
```

In order to reproduce the problem, one needs to run the code with: `ALBERT_OP="QUERY" ./script.swift`.

- What am I doing wrong in this particular case? Is it related to the fact that I am running it as a script?

Comment: `String(data: jsonD, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` not throwing any error. you can remove `try` block

Comment: Thanks. That is true, but the main problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is at `try filemgr.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "~/.snippy")`, specifically the fact that Swift doesn't automatically expand tildes in paths.  You can manually do it with `("~/.snippy" as NSString).expandingTildeInPath`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to find out the issue for soo long...